# How to stop rxjs timer

Tags: typescript, timer, rxjs

I have the following timer:

```
setCountDown() {
        let counter = 5;
        let tick = 1000;
        this.countDown = timer(0, tick)
        .pipe(
          take(counter),
          map(() => --counter),
          finalize(() => {
            if (this.currentQuestionNumber < this.questionsToAsk)
              this.showNextQuestion();
            else {
              this.endQuiz();
            }

          })
        );
      }
```

How can I stop the timer? E.g. when a user clicks on a button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using angular, if you use javascript only you can just us `fromEvent()` to create userClick

```
userClick=new Subject()

click(){userClick.next()}

setCountDown() {
        let counter = 5;
        let tick = 1000;
        this.countDown = timer(0, tick)
        .pipe(
          take(counter),
          map(() => --counter),
          takeUntil(userClick),
          finalize(() => {
            if (this.currentQuestionNumber < this.questionsToAsk)
              this.showNextQuestion();
            else {
              this.endQuiz();
            }

          })
        );
      }
```

Comment: What if I do not want `finalize` to be executed if the counter is interrupted by `takeUntil`

Comment: I see that as a second question, structure needs to be changed