# How to stop an rxjs interval/timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, intervals

I found a couple of examples where one can start/stop an `rxjs` timer or interval, however I'm having trouble getting my timer to stop.

**HTML snippet below:**

FYI: Pressing `autoPlay()` the first time will fire my auto-play interval. Clicking again will turn OFF auto-play.

My Angular `(click)` event will trigger `autoPlay()` just fine, and my `this.toggleMe` works as expected (flips value between true and false every 1 second).

```html
<mat-slide-toggle #toggleMe color="primary" [checked]="toggleMe"></mat-slide-toggle>
<div>
  <mat-icon svgIcon="auto-flipper" (click)="autoPlay()"></mat-icon>
</div>

<!-- example of the two panels that are shown/hidden based on slide-toggle above -->
<show-panel-one
  [hidden]="toggleMe.checked"
></show-panel-one>

<show-panel-two
  [hidden]="!toggleMe.checked"
></show-panel-two>
```

However, I'm trying to clear the interval via the `Subject`; namely, `this.stopPlay$.next();`. But it won't stop the interval .

```js
import { Component, ... } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "auto-play",
    templateUrl: "./auto-play.component.html",
})

export class MyTestComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

autoPlay = false;
stopPlay$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
@ViewChild("examToggle") examToggle: MatSlideToggle;

constructor() {}

autoPlay(): void {
 this.autoPlay = !this.autoPlay;
 if (!this.autoPlay) {
  this.stopPlay$.next();
 }
 const autoPlayInter = interval(1000);
 autoPlayInter.subscribe(() => {
  this.toggleMe.checked = !this.toggleMe.checked;
 });
 autoPlayInter.pipe(
  // map((_) => {}),
  takeUntil(this.stopPlay$),  // Shouldn't the .next() above trigger the timer stop ?
 );        
 }
 
}
```

It would be great to know what I'm doing wrong.

Some of my references:

[How to stop rxjs timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810643/how-to-stop-rxjs-timer) 
[Restart the timer on an rxjs interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716687/restart-the-timer-on-an-rxjs-interval)

*** UPDATE - FINAL VERSION ***

```js
autoSwitch(): void {
        this.autoPlay = !this.autoPlay;

        if (this.autoPlay) {
            this.autoPlayInter = timer(0, 2000)
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(this.stopPlay$),
                    tap((_) => (this.toggleMe.checked = !this.toggleMe.checked)),
                )
                .subscribe();
        } else {

            this.stopPlay$.next(); // this stops the timer
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to the piped observable, i.e. `autoPlayInter.pipe(...).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering the updated code:

should change to something like the following:

```
autoPlay() {
    this.autoPlay = !this.autoPlay;

    if (this.autoPlay) {
        this.autoPlayInter = interval(2000);
        this.autoPlayInter
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.stopPlay$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.examToggle.checked = !this.examToggle.checked;
            });
    } else {
        this.stopPlay$.next();
    }
 }
```

Comment: that's EXACTLY what we came up with just a few minutes ! I realized also that .next() was needed in my else. So I'll set your's as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should change this:

```
const autoPlayInter = interval(1000);
autoPlayInter.subscribe(() => (this.toggleMe.checked = !this.toggleMe.checked));
autoPlayInter.pipe(takeUntil(this.stopPlay$));
```

to this:

```
const autoPlayInter = interval(1000);
autoPlayInter
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.stopPlay$))
    .subscribe(() => (this.toggleMe.checked = !this.toggleMe.checked));
```

**the reason:**
`takeUntil` affects the subscriber, not the source.

Comment: of course I just realized that every time the user clicks on AUTOPLAY icon, I keep recreating the interval(). I want to either start it, or clear it. That's my bug.

Comment: I still cannot stop the interval. Please see updated code above.

Comment: @bob.mazzo see new answer